# How to Delete / Hide / Disable [OK] button on message box

Tags: inno-setup

Here's the code...

```pascal
ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif
const
  MB_TIMEDOUT = 32000;
  MB_ICONERROR = $10;
  MB_ICONQUESTION = $20;
  MB_ICONWARNING = $30;
  MB_ICONINFORMATION = $40;

function MessageBoxTimeout(hWnd: HWND; lpText: string; lpCaption: string;
  uType: UINT; wLanguageId: Word; dwMilliseconds: DWORD): Integer;
  external 'MessageBoxTimeout{#AW}@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  MessageBoxTimeout(WizardForm.Handle, 'Some ' +
    'message', 'Setup', MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION, 0, 5000);
end;
```

I just want the message box to appear without the button. What code to be added or removed? Where would I insert it? Thanks!

Does this a code from [How to disable the “Next” button on the wizard form in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18855000/7119414) work with my script? I can't seem to to make it working.

Comment: I've added some code to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

But as you already know from [MsgBox - Make unclickable OK Button and change to countdown - Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40446269/850848), you can implement the message box from a scratch yourself. This way, you can customize it any way you want.

Actually, all you need is to remove the button from my answer to the above question.

```pascal
[Code]

function SetTimer(hWnd: LongWord; nIDEvent, uElapse: LongWord; 
  lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord; external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';
function KillTimer(hWnd: HWND; uIDEvent: LongWord): BOOL;
  external 'KillTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  TimeoutForm: TSetupForm;

procedure TimeoutProc(H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
begin
  TimeoutForm.Tag := TimeoutForm.Tag - 1;
  if TimeoutForm.Tag = 0 then
  begin
    TimeoutForm.Close;
  end;
end;

procedure TimeoutMessageBoxCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  { Prevent the dialog from being closed by the X button and Alt-F4 }
  CanClose := (TimeoutForm.Tag = 0);
end;

procedure TimeoutMessageBox(Message: string; Seconds: Integer);
var
  MessageLabel: TLabel;
  Timer: LongWord;
begin
  TimeoutForm := CreateCustomForm;
  try
    TimeoutForm.ClientWidth := ScaleX(256);
    TimeoutForm.ClientHeight := ScaleY(64);
    TimeoutForm.Caption := 'Information';
    TimeoutForm.Position := poMainFormCenter;
    TimeoutForm.OnCloseQuery := @TimeoutMessageBoxCloseQuery;
    TimeoutForm.Tag := Seconds;

    MessageLabel := TLabel.Create(TimeoutForm);
    MessageLabel.Top := ScaleY(16);
    MessageLabel.Left := ScaleX(16);
    MessageLabel.AutoSize := True;
    MessageLabel.Caption := Message;
    MessageLabel.Parent := TimeoutForm;

    Timer := SetTimer(0, 0, 1000, CreateCallback(@TimeoutProc));

    try
      TimeoutForm.ShowModal();
    finally
      KillTimer(0, Timer);
    end;
  finally
    TimeoutForm.Free();
    TimeoutForm := nil;
  end;
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*

[image]