# Hide X button (close) at message box in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

How to hide X button at message box?

[image]

I want to see this, if is possible:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think this is possible.

One possible workaround is to implement the message box from the scratch.

And remove the `biSystemMenu` from the `TForm.BorderIcons` (or actually setting it empty).

```pascal
procedure MyMessageBoxWithoutCloseButton;
var
  Form: TSetupForm;
  Button: TNewButton;
  MesssageLabel: TLabel;
begin
  Form := CreateCustomForm;
  Form.BorderStyle := bsDialog;
  Form.Position := poOwnerFormCenter;
  Form.ClientWidth := ScaleX(400);
  Form.ClientHeight := ScaleY(130);
  Form.BorderIcons := []; { No close button }
  Form.Caption := 'Caption';

  MesssageLabel := TLabel.Create(Form);
  MesssageLabel.Parent := Form;
  MesssageLabel.Left := ScaleX(16);
  MesssageLabel.Top := ScaleX(16);
  MesssageLabel.Width := Form.ClientWidth - 2*ScaleX(16);
  MesssageLabel.Height := ScaleY(32);
  MesssageLabel.AutoSize := False;
  MesssageLabel.WordWrap := True;
  MesssageLabel.Caption := 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...';

  Button := TNewButton.Create(Form);
  Button.Parent := Form;
  Button.Width := ScaleX(80);
  Button.Height := ScaleY(24);
  Button.Left := Form.ClientWidth - Button.Width - ScaleX(8);
  Button.Top := Form.ClientHeight - Button.Height - ScaleY(8);
  Button.Caption := 'Accept';
  Button.ModalResult := mrOK;

  Form.ShowModal;
end;
```

[image: No close button]

---

*Note that it's still possible to close the message box using <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd>.*

*To prevent that handle `OnCloseQuery`. For an example, see [How to Delete / Hide / Disable [OK] button on message box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40459432/850848).*